# jersey (dropwizard) default media type for @Produces and @Consumes

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

By default, all the methods in our application will be JSON based. I'd like to avoid adding @Produces and @Consumes(might be optional, not sure) to each and every Resource class like below.

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestResource {

  @GET
  public TestClass test() {
    return new TestClass();
  }
}
```

Currently it uses **application/octet-stream** if I don't define media type. I was hoping there would be a way to change it to something else via jersey's ResourceConfig or something. Looked around in the source code but got lost.

Currently dropwizard uses jersey 1.18 but it will be updated to 2.0 soon (hopefully :)). So answers for both versions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can be done via ContainerRequestFilter. There you can modify the ACCEPT Header. If you set this to json only, then this can help. Have you tried to set the ACCEPT header field in your REST Client to JSON only? Does this help?

Or you just build your Response with json like this:

```
@GET
@Path("get")
public Response getInTestResource()
{
    return Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity("get is ok").build();
}
```

But one question: Is this really too mutch work, if you document, what this method consumes or produces? I think the annotationis not too mutch additional work ...

Comment: looks like `ContainerRequestFilter` and `ContainerResponseFilter` is a solution, though I'm not sure what kind of overheads it will add to the system. But it's good enough.

As for the other suggestions:
- From what I can remember from the jersey source code, adding `ACCEPT` to request header on client would work. But I was looking for a server-side solution and a whitelisting(only JSON) solution.
- Returning Response object is something I prefer to avoid as it's fairly ugly compared to returning the entity class directly. And it's actually even more boilerplate than the annotations.

Comment: As for the question: 
No, it's not really too much work nor very ugly. It's just a best-effort attempt to keep the code-base as clean and free-from code duplication as possible. It should be noted also that it's a multi-service with multi-resources project which could mean extra duplicate 50-100 annotations over each resource class.